# How to sort alphanumeric string in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2008-r2

i want to sort an alphanumberic string...

sample string :

```
D12,D13
F19,F20
A12,A13
F10,F11
D14
A1,A2
A5,A6
D4,D5
F5,F6,F7
```

Desired Output :

```
A1,A2
A5,A6
A12,A13
D4,D5
D12,D13
D14
F5,F6,F7
F10,F11
F19,F20
```

HELP ME !!!!

Comment: This is not a good process to try to do in SQL.  Can you do it in your calling application instead?

Comment: Is it always a single alpha character at the beginning?

Comment: Oy. Not only is this double-parsing because you have groups of strings you want to sort together, the number of strings in a group isn't even consistent (the last group has 3 elements, not 2). I'd suggest that CLR or your application code are far better optimized for sorting these strings than T-SQL will ever be.

Comment: Can you please specify what version of SQL Server you are using? Also I took the liberty of editing the title (no need to yell).

Comment: @Aaron Bertrand I am using sql server 2008 R2.

Comment: @Joe Stefanelli no there are some string like AA1,AA2 ,but in all the  string i can ignore the additional item after comma because its always a preceding value..

Comment: So can you list some of these other edge cases? Where would AA1,AA2 and FA2,FA5 sort?

Comment: What is the maximum number of delimited values in the string? Is it something like 5 or is it too dynamic to determine?

Comment: @Aaron Bertrand AA1,AA2 must be sort after Z98,Z99

Comment: @ K Richard maximum number of delimiter is 5

Comment: **when something as simple as a sort becomes difficult, you can be sure that a poor design is causing it.**  correct the issue, by changing the table. never store more than one value per column.  here I see a comma delimited list of compound values.  split the compound value (letters-numbers) into two columns (one for the letter portion and one for the number).  Also, split out the comma separated list into additional rows, and then the `ORDER BY` will be simple.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on new requirements and loosely on @kuru kuru's answer, I hope this order by clause demonstrates why normalization is a good thing. Just because it's good for JSON and Ajax doesn't mean it's how you should treat your database:

```
DECLARE @t TABLE (x VARCHAR(32));

INSERT @t VALUES
  ('D12,D13'),
  ('F19,F20'),
  ('A12,A13'),
  ('F10,F11'),
  ('D14'),
  ('A1,A2'),
  ('A5,A6'),
  ('D4,D5'),
  ('F5,F6,F7'),
  ('AA1,AA2'),
  ('Z98,Z99');

SELECT x FROM @t
ORDER BY CASE 
    WHEN UPPER(x) LIKE '[A-Z][A-Z]%'
    THEN 'Z' + LEFT(x,2) ELSE LEFT(x,1) END,
    CONVERT(INT, 
      CASE WHEN x LIKE '%,%' THEN 
        SUBSTRING(x, PATINDEX('%[0-9]%', x), 
        CHARINDEX(',', x)-PATINDEX('%[0-9]%', x))
      ELSE 
        SUBSTRING(x, PATINDEX('%[0-9]%', x), 32)
      END
    );
```

Comment: `A12,A13` is sorting before `A1,A2`

Comment: IN THIS CASE F5,F6,F7 COMES AFTER F19,F20 AND F10,F11

Comment: I wouldn't consider this a good thing. It's an ugly hack that barely hides a horrible underlying design. But, glad to help. :-)

Comment: Yes i know that but changing in live database having large structure and size is not possible..... anyways thanks once again.

Comment: Well, I'd be curious to see how poorly this runs if you try to perform this sort against a "large structure and size"... hopefully you pull back a small set of rows and only apply the sort as a second step.

Comment: Great! Don't be offended, can't take anything for granted.

Comment: @vivek, you could add two persisted computed columns on this table, basically the two generated columns in the order by from this answer (`CASE 
    WHEN UPPER(x) LIKE '[A-Z][A-Z]%'
    THEN 'Z' + LEFT(x,2) ELSE LEFT(x,1) END` and `CONVERT(INT, 
      CASE WHEN x LIKE '%,%' THEN 
        SUBSTRING(x, PATINDEX('%[0-9]%', x), 
        CHARINDEX(',', x)-PATINDEX('%[0-9]%', x))
      ELSE 
        SUBSTRING(x, PATINDEX('%[0-9]%', x), 32)
      END
    )`).  you could then sort by them in the normal way, with much less overhead.  Also, don't forget to accept the answer that solves your question.

Comment: Well, the overhead incurred here really depends on how often the table is inserted/updated compared to how many times the query is run - a persisted computed column is not free, and if there are more writes than reads, it may not be the best approach. Never a simple answer. :-)

Comment: This is not sorting the delimited values within the string

Comment: @K Richard, please review the requirements, the values after the first comma do not need to be sorted because the OP stated they are always successive.

Answer (score 1):

As @JNK and @Aaron Bertrand have mentioned, T-SQL is not really the best choice for this task.

Having said that, there are a couple of issues to tackle.

1. You're going to have to separate each item into two components, the alpha part and the numeric part, otherwise there is no way "A5,..." is going to be sorted before "A12,...", since "A5" comes after "A1" when comparing string values. You'll have to parse the values and turn "A5" into "A05" (or however many significant digits you need) in order to get a correct sort order.
2. Are you ignoring the additional item(s) after the comma in each string? If the answer is no, then you'll have to do the processing described in #1 on each value in the string. For example, is it possible to have "A5, A6" and you want that value sorted before "A5, A12"?

Once you have normalized the values in the strings, then you can tackle the comparison and sorting.

Comment: Thanks for answering man. My Answer is yes,I am ignoring the additional item after comma in each of the string, because
its a preceding value of the first alphanumeric value before comma. an that is fixed. so now is sorting is possible?

Comment: But it's not a numeric value, as far as the sorting algorithm is concerned. It is a string. So the comparison will start with the first character, in this case both are 'A'. Then on to the second character, 'A5' vs. 'A1'. The comparison says A1 comes before A5, even though by looking at it, you know it is really A5 vs. A12. So you must normalize the numeric part before you can do a true sort. 'A05' vs. 'A12'.

Comment: but cant we separate '12' in this case?

Answer (score 0):

I can't believe everyone's saying all those mean things about TSQL.  :-)

You don't have to normalize the data before you sort it.  (Well, not explicitly in any case -- the SQL engine can just wear some beer-goggles when it processes the ORDER BY clause, and it will work fine).

Here's a sample that works in TSQL...  I know it *looks like* there's no reason for the right side to order properly, but it does actually order properly.

```
declare @table TABLE (item varchar(10))
insert into @table(item) values('FF5')
insert into @table(item) values('Z10')
insert into @table(item) values('F15')
insert into @table(item) values('F20')
insert into @table(item) values('A7')
insert into @table(item) values('A12')

SELECT
    item
FROM
    @table
ORDER BY
    CASE WHEN SUBSTRING(item,2,1) LIKE '[A-Z]' THEN LEFT(item,2) ELSE LEFT(item,1) END
```

Comment: Did you try it, or are you just saying that?  I ran it, and it does sort properly for me (SQL-Server 2005 & 2008)

Comment: OK -- now he says there's possibly two alpha characters on the left...back to the query window...

Comment: OK @Filip -- Now it works again -- just had to change the order by to account for two alphas on the left.

Comment: it doesnt sort correctly.. there is a string which is having two values like A11,A12 seperated by comma...

Comment: darn -- changed requirements again in latest comment -- back to the drawing board.

Comment: @kuru this is called a "moving target"

Comment: @Aaron -- :-P  I give up.  I was trying so hard not to take the normalize-first approach but...*sigh*

Comment: @KURU how to short AA1,AA2 after z98,z99 ?

Comment: @vivek please try my answer again